# Collapsible controls in MFC (example included)

Tags: mfc, windows

In the WindowsXP Control panel, you can see a nice collapsible panel control on the left:

[image]
<sub>(source: [leeindy.com](http://screenshots.leeindy.com/ControlPanel/category_view.gif))</sub>

These are not just collapsible, but animated too. I wondered if these are any kind of control accessible to a developer, specifically in MFC? Or are they custom/bespoke functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 with the MFC Feature Pack, have a look at the [`CMFCTasksPane`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984027.aspx) class. The Feature Pack includes a TaskPane sample application that demonstrates how to use this.

Comment: MFC Feature Pack is included with VS2008 SP1

Comment: Is it possible to use it for NON-task purpose, such as including textboxes and traditional buttons?